# How to automate Batch monitoring jobs

Tags: jcl

We have a set of BMP's called the batch monitoring jobs which runs whole day ( execution status always) and they are bought up running a start job.

we need to see that the BMP's are always under execution status, I want to automate this so that it can monitor these BMP's and notify us when they are down, so that we can make them up.

Could you please help me how i can proceed

Answer (score 1):

Most mainframes have a scheduling application where jobs will start either manually or there are start conditions (in this case the condition would be a time like 6:00AM) then if there are multiple jobs, there can be conditions that will kick off the other jobs.